# SQL to search the entire table for a string

Tags: sql, database, insert

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Search</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function query() {
    var adVarWChar = 202;
    var adParamInput = 1;
    var pad = "C:\\Users\\azi!z\\Desktop\\Project\\Test.accdb";
    var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;
    cn.Open(strConn);
    var cm = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
    cm.ActiveConnection = cn;
    cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel WHERE Module LIKE ? OR TestCase LIKE ? OR Openedby LIKE ? OR Status LIKE ?";
    //cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel where TestCase LIKE ?";
    cm.Parameters.Append(cm.CreateParameter(
            "?", 
            adVarWChar, 
            adParamInput, 
            255, 
            "%" + document.getElementById("searchTerm").value + "%"));
    var rs = cm.Execute();  // returns ADODB.Recordset object
    if (rs.EOF) {
        document.write("<p>No data found.</p>");
    } else {
        while (!rs.EOF) {
        document.write("<p>" + rs.fields(0).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(1).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(2).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(3).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(4).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(5).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(6).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(7).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(8).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(9).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(10).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(11).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(12).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(13).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(14).value + ", ");
        document.write(rs.fields(15).value + ".</p>");
        var row = row.parentNode.rows[ ++idx ];
            document.write(rs.fields(1).value + ".</p>");
            rs.MoveNext();
        }
    }
    rs.Close();
    cn.Close();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get" name="SearchEngine" target="_blank">
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong>EA Search Engine</strong></span></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><input maxlength="300" id="searchTerm" name="KeywordSearch" size="100" type="text" value="Enter Your Keyword Here" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><input name="Search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="query();" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me modify the SELECT statement in such a way that it covers the entire table (Not just the "TestCase" column) for ?.

Tried with changing the SELECT query to "SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel WHERE col1 LIKE ? OR col2 LIKE ? OR col3 LIKE ?; ...", but it's not working.

Comment: edit the question with 'SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel WHERE col1 LIKE ? OR col2 LIKE ? OR col3 LIKE ? ' version you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create table dynamically using Javascript to display a database SELECT query output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569820/create-table-dynamically-using-javascript-to-display-a-database-select-query-out)

Comment: No. That's different.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search string in all columns of your table
you can concatenate all columns values and search value in the new column. For example

```
SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel 
WHERE Module
        & column1
        & column2 
        & column3 like '*substring*'
```

Comment: Changed the SELECT statement to cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel WHERE Module 
 & TestCase 
 & OpenedBy
 & Screen like ?";

Not getting the result. @fabulaspb

Comment: Try change string pattern from `%substring%` to `*substring*`

Comment: @AziizPc I've created simple table in the MS Access and tried query like this `SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel WHERE Module & TestCase & OpenedBy & Status like '*ed*'`. It perfectly works. What error did you receive?

Comment: But, I want the search keyword to be taken from the textbox which is defined as "?" now. That is,  '*?*'  or  '%?%'  is not working.

Comment: Okey. Try this. `SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel WHERE Module & TestCase & OpenedBy & Status like ?` Replace ? to value. `cm.Parameters.Append(cm.CreateParameter(
            "?", 
            adVarWChar, 
            adParamInput, 
            255, 
            "*" + document.getElementById("searchTerm").value + "*"));`

Comment: Tried that. Now, the Searching itself is not working. #Help @fabulaspb